# Не работает параметр проигрывателя YouTube autoplay

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Почему-то видео на странице начинает проигрываться автоматически, хотя устанавливаю параметр **autoplay:0**.

Тоже самое происходит с кодом который полностью скопирован с **"YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds"**. При этом для этого кода параметр автозапуска не работает, но работает соседний controls.

Поэтому не могу понять в чем может быть проблема.

**Код следующий:**

```js
        window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {

            player = new YT.Player('video', {
                width: 1280,
                height: 720,
                playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 1 },
                events: {
                    'onReady': onPlayerReady
                }
            });

        }

        function onPlayerReady(event) {

            $(btnPlay).on("click", function() {

                var videoId = $(this).attr("data-src");

                if (lastButton == videoId) {
                    player.playVideo(videoId);
                } else {
                    player.loadVideoById(videoId);
                    lastButton = videoId;
                }

            });

            $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                player.pauseVideo();
            });

        }
```

**P.S.**
Проверка в **onPlayerReady** используется так как у меня видео выводится в модальном окне Бутстрапа.

При клике на ссылке на странице из его data атрибута содержащего id (видео из youtube) получаем его и проверяем была ли уже загружена это видео или нет.

Если была, то запускаем, а если нет, то загружаем.

Comment: Понял почему он запускается хотя стоит 'autoplay': 0, дело в том что далее видео запускает player.playVideo(videoId).

На самом деле все работает, просто ниже переопределяется.

Осталось понять как присвоить id видео не запустив его.

Answer (score 0):

**Решение следующее:** 
У YouTube есть функция **cueVideoById** служащая для загрузки значка определенного видео и ***подготовки проигрывателя к воспроизведению*** видеофайла.

Если его использовать вместо **.playVideo()**, то он просто загрузит видео и не будет запускать.

```
    var player;
    var btnPlay = $(".arrival__video");
    var lastButton = "";

    window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {

        player = new YT.Player('video', {
            width: 1280,
            height: 720,
            playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 1 },
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady
            }
        });

    }

    function onPlayerReady(event) {

        $(btnPlay).on("click", function() {

            var videoId = $(this).attr("data-src");

            if (lastButton != videoId) {
                player.cueVideoById(videoId);
                lastButton = videoId;
            }

        });

        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            player.pauseVideo();
        });

    }
```